# Convert all Grayscale pixel value to black

Tags: python, opencv

I am calculating the histogram of a gray scale image and i want to convert the range of grayscale pixel to black. I am using the following code to retrieve the histogram.`

```
image = cv2.imread('./images/test/image_5352.jpg')
cv2.imshow("image", image)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow("gray", gray)

hist = cv2.calcHist([gray], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])
plt.figure()
plt.title("Grayscale Histogram")
plt.xlabel("Bins")
plt.ylabel("# of Pixels")
plt.plot(hist)
plt.xlim([0, 256])
key = cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: Histogram of the image]

For example i want to convert all the pixels with value of 50 to black.

Comment: Pretty sure this is what you want, if it is, feel free to answer this question with the specifics http://answers.opencv.org/question/97416/replace-a-range-of-colors-with-a-specific-color-in-python/

Comment: I believe opencv returns numpy arrays for images. You can use boolean indexing to manipulate the image: `gray[gray==50] = 0` should work.

Comment: What about pixels of 49? And 51?

Comment: @umutto Thank you changing the numpy array got me the result

Comment: @MarkSetchell used for loop to change range of pixels for me

Comment: @faizanbaig No problem, also if you need to change a range of values you can use multiple equations. I.E. `gray[(20<gray) & (gray<50)] = 0` would be easier to read and more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe image thresholding is what you're after...

> If pixel value is greater than a threshold value, it is assigned one value (may be white), else it is assigned another value (may be black).

`cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)`

The above code is in C++ but easy enough to convert. The first parameter is the image in question, the second is the threshold value, the third is what to assign any pixel values to if it surpasses the threshold, and the fourth is the thresholding type in which there are multiple:

[image]

For further reading: [see here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#threshold)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i dont want to change all the pixels into black and white just want to change some pixels in certain range

Comment: Ah okay, I missread then. Couldn't you just use broadcasting? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Answer (score 0):

openCV in range is what you need. You could use in range to produce mask.

http://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga48af0ab51e36436c5d04340e036ce981/

You could do that inside following procedure

```
cv::Mat mask;
cv::inRange(src,40,60,mask);
cv::bitwise_not(mask,mask);
cv::bitwise_and(src,mask);
```